# Exchange smallest index in array with another Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to parse through my array where it will find the smallest number, move it to the front, and swap that [0] number with the small number. So swapping places basically.
I am using a for loop to parse through and find the smallest number, however, it is outputting the 3rd smallest number in the front. I am sure it is a small mistake. Please provide a mini explanation, I want to make sure I understand.

CODE:

```
int [] arr = { 123, 177, 127, 173, 187, 148, 187, 94, 76, 61, 123, 78, 121, 5, 71, 139, 13, 18, 97, 144, 50, 137, 96, 36, 1, 162, 161, 21 }

public static void moveSmallestToLeft(int[] arr) {
        int tmp = arr[0];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] < tmp) {
                arr[0] = i;
                i = tmp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

Output I am getting:

```
[7, 177, 127, 173, 187, 148, 187, 94, 76, 61, 123, 78, 121, 5, 71, 139, 13, 18, 97, 144, 50, 137, 96, 36, 1, 162, 161, 21]
```

As you can see, 7 isn't the smallest number in the array. It is 1... any way I can tweak it to swap correct indexes? Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: I see a couple of minor mistakes that could be causing this. First, when you reference i in the if statement, you are referencing the index when I believe you should be referencing arr[i]. Secondly, you're not resetting the tmp variable, which I believe you should be. Combined, I think you may get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using index (i) instead of values in the `for` loop in your function, the loop should be

```
for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] < arr[0]) {
        tmp = arr[0];
        arr[0] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Makes sense. Good learning lesson. Thank you!!